# Use AppleScript to block a sender

Tags: outlook, applescript, outlook-2011

I would like to block a spammer's address using AppleScript.

With the Inbox message selected, I execute this script:

```
tell application "System Events"

    click menu item "Block Sender" in menu item "Junk Mail" in menu bar item "Message" in menu bar 1 of application process "Microsoft Outlook"

end tell
```

Which results in this error:

> System Events got an error: Can’t get menu item "Junk Mail" of menu
>   bar item "Message" of menu bar 1 of application process "Microsoft
>   Outlook".

The `Junk Mail` menu has a submenu:

[image]

The AppleScript Editor has been granted access to control my computer:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really test it with Outlook, but you missed to tell the menus "Message" and "Junk Mail" of the menu items:

```
tell application "System Events"

    click menu item ¬
         "Block Sender" in menu ¬
         "Junk Mail" in menu item ¬
         "Junk Mail" in menu ¬
         "Message" in menu bar item ¬
         "Message" in menu bar 1 ¬
         of application process "Microsoft Outlook"

end tell
```

Comment: This does run without producing an error, but it doesn't actually seem to add the sender to the Blocked Senders list.

Comment: You may need to add `tell application "Microsoft Outlook" to activate` before you first `tell`